# Can I put many keys in a collection of mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want store a hash-like value in mongodb.

There are two collection, person and work. A person has some works with quantity. Work store in the other collection with more details(maybe reference the other collections).

eg. Person(Jim) has one work(a) and three works(b).

```
// Person
{
    _id: "4d772583c186233352000001"
    name: "Jim"
    works: {
        "4d772583c186233352000002": 1
        "4d772583c186233352000003": 3
        ...
    }
}

// Work
{
    _id: "4d772583c186233352000002"
    title: "Make cake"
    finished_at: ...
}
{
    _id: "4d772583c186233352000003"
    title: "Make iPhone"
    finished_at: ...
}
...
```

If I store works property of person like above. Person key path will include work's id and increase again and again. Is this right way?

Comment: In Rich-Web project. We need serialize data from server to client. The first data style will become to a dictionary. Otherwise we must deal with an array and some dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure that I understand the actual question here. Are you asking for a second opinion on your schema design? If so, here's mine:

There's absolutely nothing wrong with keeping relations between collections using document id:s like you have done. Sometimes that is the right (and only) way to go, even though you have to take on the responsibility of maintaining the relationships/references yourself since, as you probably know, mongoDB will not help you with that.

It's a bit hard for me, though, to understand your use cases by just looking at the sample schema above, but what catches my eye is the works-object.

I think you'll be better off using an array - perhaps like this:

```
 works: [
        { "4d772583c186233352000002": 1 },
        { "4d772583c186233352000003": 3 }
 ]
```

That way you will have better support from mongo in maintaining your references, using for example the $pull and $push operators.

But then I'm wondering also about using the foreign id reference as a key in the work reference object. For more idiomatic objects, consider this:

```
works : [
     { work_id: "4d772583c186233352000002", quantity: 1 },
     { work_id: "4d772583c186233352000003", quantity: 3 }
]
```

Does that help?

Comment: I worry about the key is mutable. If I have large data. Will mongodb slow down? I cannot image how to build index for them.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about the key being mutable.

Obviously, the more data you put in, the slower mongo will be. But you can have very large amounts of documents of these types before that will be noticeable (unless you have very specific performance requirements). Just be sure that your queries will use your indexes.

About the index, if you mean that you will be wanting to query for a Person who holds a reference to a specific work, you can easily do that by adding an index on "works.works_id", `db.persons.ensureIndex({"works.works_id" : 1})`